# How can I generate row_number by condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, row-number

I am trying to put conditional numbering depending on a result from row_num column.

When the flg_start_trx is 1, I would like to have new column with brand new increment by 1 and it will stop when found the end of flg_session_match != 1

[image]

How can I fix this query if I want the result should be like row_num column?

```
case when (title is not null and title_program is null)
         then (row_number() over (partition by flg_session_match,(case when (title is not null and title_program is null) then 1 else 0 end)
                           )
              )
    end as start_session
```

Comment: I think you need an extra column by which you can order your data, i.e. timestamp or autoincrement id. For example, for title A there are 6 rows and one of them has a not null value for "title_program" and "flg_start_trx"; how could we know that this row is in the third position within the A group?

Comment: I have a timestamp and id in each record

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

(As @Ahmed mentioned above, you need a column to define an order of each row, so I've added **ts** for that purpose.)

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(par0, par1),
       IF (FIRST_VALUE(flg_start_trx) OVER w1 IS NOT NULL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER w1, NULL) AS row_num
 FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER w0 - COUNTIF(flg_start_trx IS NULL) OVER w0 AS par0,
         COUNT(*) OVER w0 - COUNTIF(flg_session_match = 1) OVER w0 AS par1
    FROM sample_data
  WINDOW w0 AS (ORDER BY ts)
) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY par0, par1 ORDER BY ts);
```

[image]